# Using Left Join in an Insert Statement MsAccess

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to take this select statement and use it to insert the results into a new table.

```
INSERT INTO [DataALL]
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Data 2015].[Sort ID],
[Data 2015].[Sort ID Description],
[Data 2015].[Customer],
[Data 2015].[Customer ID],
[Data 2015].[Invoice Nbr],
[Data 2015].[Src Sys],
[Data 2015].[HCC],
[Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 1],
[Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 2],
[Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 3],
[Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 4], 
[Data 2015].[EID], 
[Data 2015].[HCID], 
[Data 2015].[Last Name],
[Data 2015].[First Name],
[Data 2015].[Incurred Date],
[Data 2015].[Paid Date],
[Data 2015].[Claim Nbr],
[Data 2015].[Servc Plan],
[Data 2015].[TOC],
[Data 2015].[Sex Rel],
[Data 2015].[Reimburse Amount],
[EE Status Desc].[Employee Status Desc],
[Operating Company Mapping].[NiSource_CPG]

FROM ([Data 2015]
LEFT JOIN [EE Status Desc]
ON MID([Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 2],3,1) = [EE Status Desc].[Employee Status])
LEFT JOIN [Operating Company Mapping]
ON MID([Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 4],2,2) = [Operating Company Mapping].[Operating Company]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the columns you want to insert into: (they are in parens on the first line below)

```
INSERT INTO [DataALL] ([Sort ID], [Sort ID Description], ...)
SELECT [Data 2015].[Sort ID], ... FROM [Data 2015]
LEFT JOIN [EE Status Desc]
ON MID([Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 2],3,1) = [EE Status Desc].[Employee Status])
LEFT JOIN [Operating Company Mapping]
ON MID([Data 2015].[Bill Lvl 4],2,2) = [Operating Company Mapping].[Operating Company]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Barett for your solution! I am now hitting an error stating that I cannot open database ".

Comment: Thanks so much @Barett! I re-compacted my database and everything works! Thanks so much!